# MVC project Role based authentication for admin and normal user using database for getting role details

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

The Role-based authentication system where there will be some admin and some normal users. I am trying to configure the system in such a way that depending on the role of the user they will be able to login using different URLs and after that, they can perform their intended task. The following code is used for the configuration

This is for userDetail

```java
    package com.multiauthentication.config;

    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;
    
    import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    
    import com.multiauthentication.entity.User;
    
    public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
    
    private User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority simpleGrantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getUserRole());

        return List.of(simpleGrantedAuthority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmailAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    }
```

This is for userService detail

```java
    package com.multiauthentication.service;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
    
    import com.multiauthentication.config.CustomUserDetails;
    import com.multiauthentication.dao.UserRepository;
    import com.multiauthentication.entity.User;
    
    public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        // Fetch user from Database
        User user = this.userRepository.getUserByUserEmail(username);

        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not found user");
        }

        CustomUserDetails userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(user);

        return userDetails;
    }

    }
```

And this is for application configuration

```java
    package com.multiauthentication.config;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
    import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
    
    import com.multiauthentication.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService getDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(this.getDetailsService());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder());

        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    // Configure Method
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class AppConfigurationAdapter1 {

        // Configure HttpSecurity for Admin
        @Bean
        protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain1(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/loginAdmin")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/admin_login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/index")
            
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/admin_logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/protectedLinks")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/403")
            
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();

            return http.build();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class AppConfigurationAdapter2 {

        // Configure HttpSecurity for User
        @Bean
        protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("NORMAL")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/loginUser")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/user_login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/index")
            
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/user_logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/protectedLinks")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")

            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/403")

            .and()
            .csrf().disable();

            return http.build();
        }
    }

    }
```

The entity class is defined and declared in the following way

```java
    package com.multiauthentication.entity;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    
    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.Getter;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.Setter;
    import lombok.ToString;
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;
    
    @Column(name = "email_address")
    private String emailAddress;
    
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name = "user_role")
    private String userRole;
    
    @Column(name = "user_enabled")
    private boolean userEnabled;
    }
```

The login for Admin is properly working and able to hit the `defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/index")` but for the normal it is not. Whenever the I tried to login using credentials of normal user it get stuck on `loginProcessingUrl("/user_login")` for your reference I am attaching both page for user login and response after that I get.

[image: User Login Page]

[image: User Login Response received]

The Following logs is related to admin role which is successfull

```
    2022-10-23 09:49:16.992[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GET "/loginAdmin", parameters={}
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:16.993[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to com.multiauthentication.controller.BasicController#customAdminLogin(Model)
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:16.996[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:17.039[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 200 OK
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:17.050[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-9][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GET "/CSS/style.css", parameters={}
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:17.050[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GET "/JS/scriptfile.js", parameters={}
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:17.051[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-9][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:17.051[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:17.052[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 200 OK
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:17.052[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-9][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 200 OK
    Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.email_address as email_ad2_0_, user0_.password as password3_0_, user0_.user_enabled as user_ena4_0_, user0_.user_name as user_nam5_0_, user0_.user_role as user_rol6_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.email_address=?
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:31.751[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GET "/admin/index", parameters={}
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:31.751[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to com.multiauthentication.controller.AdminController#showHomeAdmin(Model, Principal)
    Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.email_address as email_ad2_0_, user0_.password as password3_0_, user0_.user_enabled as user_ena4_0_, user0_.user_name as user_nam5_0_, user0_.user_role as user_rol6_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.email_address=?
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:31.758[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:31.782[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 200 OK
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:31.791[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GET "/CSS/style.css", parameters={}
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:31.792[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:31.794[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GET "/JS/scriptfile.js", parameters={}
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:31.794[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 200 OK
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:31.795[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:31.797[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-4][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 200 OK
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:32.158[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GET "/Image/Urban%20development%20Banner.png", parameters={}
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:32.158[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
    [2m2022-10-23 09:49:32.162[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-5][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 200 OK
```

And now this log is related to normal role which is not working properly

```
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:37.407[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-9][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GET "/loginUser", parameters={}
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:37.408[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-9][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to com.multiauthentication.controller.BasicController#customUserLogin(Model)
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:37.411[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-9][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:37.455[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-9][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 200 OK
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:37.462[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GET "/CSS/style.css", parameters={}
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:37.462[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m GET "/JS/scriptfile.js", parameters={}
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:37.463[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:37.463[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:37.465[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 200 OK
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:37.465[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 200 OK
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:56.532[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m POST "/user_login", parameters={masked}
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:56.533[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:56.540[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resource not found
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:56.541[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:56.542[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={masked}
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:56.542[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:56.562[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
    [2m2022-10-23 09:55:56.562[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m13680[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Comment: Can you post the logs printed. Is there any exception printed in logs

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao I just added the logs related to both types of users admin and normal

Comment: From the logs, at least it's clear that the error is not related to authentication. It's 404 i.e. resource not found. Pls add your controller code too